# Multiply every other element in a list

Tags: python, list

I have a list, let's say: `list = [6,2,6,2,6,2,6]`, and I want it to create a new list with every other element multiplied by 2 and every other element multiplied by 1 (stays the same).
The result should be: `[12,2,12,2,12,2,12]`.

```
def multi():
    res = 0
    for i in lst[0::2]:
        return i * 2 

print(multi)
```

Maybe something like this, but I don't know how to move on from this. How is my solution wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use slice assignment and list comprehension:

```
l = oldlist[:]
l[::2] = [x*2 for x in l[::2]]
```

Your solution is wrong because:

1. The function doesn't take any arguments
2. `res` is declared as a number and not a list
3. Your loop has no way of knowing the index
4. You return on the first loop iteration
5. Not related to the function, but you didn't actually call `multi`

Here's your code, corrected:

```
def multi(lst):
    res = list(lst) # Copy the list
    # Iterate through the indexes instead of the elements
    for i in range(len(res)):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            res[i] = res[i]*2 
    return res

print(multi([12,2,12,2,12,2,12]))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can reconstruct the list with list comprehenstion and `enumerate` function, like this

```
>>> [item * 2 if index % 2 == 0 else item for index, item in enumerate(lst)]
[12, 2, 12, 2, 12, 2, 12]
```

`enumerate` function gives the current index of them item in the iterable and the current item, in each iteration. We then use the condition

```
item * 2 if index % 2 == 0 else item
```

to decide the actual value to be used. Here, `if index % 2 == 0` then `item * 2` will be used otherwise `item` will be used as it is.