# How can I mutiply every alternative elements with a number and return the list using python?

Tags: python, list

I have a list

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

I want to multiply odd elements with 2 and return

```
new_list = [2,2,6,4,10,6]
```

I can get only the alternative using list comprehension:

```
>>>>new_list = [i*2 for i in my_list[::2]]
[2, 6, 10]
```

Comment: `my_list[::2] = [i*2 for i in my_list[::2]]` ?

Comment: Also: [Multiply every other element in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26452170/7851470)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this way the numbers in the input list don't need to be sorted:

```
[i*2 if not idx%2 else i for idx,i in enumerate(my_list)]
```

you need to use indexes

Comment: The numbers should be in order. Please check his expected output.

Answer (score 3):

You may multiple the elements at odd places by 2 and retain the other elements during `list comphrehension`.

```py
new_list = [num*2 if id%2==0 else num for (id, num) in enumerate(my_list)]
```

Output

```
[2, 2, 6, 4, 10, 6]
```

Comment: this will NOT multiple the elements at odd indexes if the input list is anything else than a sequence of 1,2,3...

Comment: @T.Opletal The example in the question stated that the sequence was 1,2, 3...

Comment: @T.Opletal Wel... The only requirement is that even numbers are in the odd-numbered places and vice versa (if `new_list[n] == m`, we must have `(n + m) % 2 == 1` for all `n`)

Comment: yes, which is imo terrible assumption to make

Comment: @T.Opletal I realize it was a mistake on my part to assume this. I have edited my answer. Your answer was more correct in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
>>> [(1 + el%2)*el for el in my_list]
[2, 2, 6, 4, 10, 6]
```

---

Using the idea that for any [integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer) `el`, `el%2` can only return `0` (even) or `1` (odd). So

1. `(1 + el%2)` equals `2` when `el` is odd.
2. `(1 + el%2)` equals `1` when `el` is even.

Comment: same as 

`[i*2 for i in my_list[::2]]`

Comment: @Joseph nop mate. You miss one element over two when doing `[i*2 for i in my_list[::2]]`, i.e. your proposal returns `[2, 6, 10]`.

Answer (score 2):

The below code works:

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

new_lis=[i if i%2==0 else i*2 for i in my_list ]

print(new_lis)
```

Answer (score 1):

Go for numpy!

```
import numpy as np

my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
A = np.array(my_list )

A[::2] *= 2
```

Output:

```
array([ 2,  2,  6,  4, 10,  6])
```

Answer (score 1):

here's a solution with map and lambda :)

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

print(map(lambda x: x*2 if x%2!=0 else x, my_list))
# [2, 2, 6, 4, 10, 6]
```